# Will componentWillUnmount be called when app is closed?

Tags: react-native

I am using [react-native-audio-recorder-player](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-audio-recorder-player) to record and play audio. IF I close app while audio is being played, Audio is still playing. But In fact I called `stopAudio()` in `componentWillUnmount()`. But I noticed that `componentWillUnmount()` is not getting called when app is closed.

I would like to know two things that

1.Will `componentWillUnmount()` be called when app is closed? If not

2.Is there any way to know programmatically that app is closed?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `componentWillUnmount()` for this case, this function is not called when the application is closed.

I think you can use [react native appstate](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate)

Or you can use custom hook to stop audio  [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-appstate-hook)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import useAppState from 'react-native-appstate-hook';


export default function App() {
  const { appState } = useAppState({
    onChange: (newAppState) => console.warn('App state changed to ', newAppState),
    onForeground: () => console.warn('App went to Foreground'),
    onBackground: () => stopAudio(),
  });

return <View/>
}
```